# Paging item on vb.net listview

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I would like to separate my `ListView` items to each page. I have a problem when analyzing the code, how could my code be simplified into clean code or get some new tricks for my method of writing it? Sorry for my bad English.

I've tried counting how many pages I need, counting the last item I mod, I've also tried thinking about the best way to do this.

```
Dim Tabs_count As Integer = Nothing
Dim Tabs_item As Integer = Nothing
Public Sub Tabs(item_s As Integer)
    Dim Tab As Double = item_s / 10
    Dim LastItem As Array = Tab.ToString.Split(",")        
    Dim totalfile As Integer = item_s Mod (10 * LastItem(0))
    'tab is a number of page I need it
    'totalfiles is a number of the last item i hope to array it
End Sub
```

Programming logic: Let's say I have 100 items. I would like to separate them by 10 items per page so that I can get the `ListView` item and subitem from `JSON` files. I would like to put the JSON files in an array by link, like this:

```
Dim bunch_of_files as new list(of string)
this is loop ' 
Dim files as string = "link of JSON files"
    bunch_of files.add(files)
end of loop
```

And when I called page 1 it would be like:

```
Public sub page_called(str as int32) ' input will be (1) (2) (3) (4) ... (+)
Dim item_end as int32 = str * 10 'ex : 1 * 10 = 10
 str = str * 10 - 10
  for i as int32 = str to item_end ' 1 to 10
  listview1.item.add( bunch_of_item(i) )
next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, this should get you started in the right direction:

```
Private Sub SplitListViewButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SplitListViewButton.Click
    Try

        'I want to split my source list view into tabs with 11 list items per tab page
        splitListViewToTabs(11)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("An error occurred: ", ex.Message))
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub splitListViewToTabs(listItemsPerTabPage As Integer)

    'how many list items do I have in my source list view?
    Dim sourceListItemCount As Integer = FilesListView.Items.Count
    'how many tabs do I need?
    Dim tabCount As Integer = ((sourceListItemCount / listItemsPerTabPage) + 0.5)

    'place holder used as we copy list items from source to new listview
    Dim lastSourceListViewIndex As Integer

    'reset tab control
    SplitTabControl.TabPages.Clear()

    'start adding tabs
    For tabAdd As Integer = 1 To tabCount
        'add tab page
        SplitTabControl.TabPages.Add(tabAdd.ToString)

        'add list view
        Dim lv As New ListView With {
            .View = FilesListView.View,
            .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        }
        'copy column headers over from source list view
        For Each listviewCol As ColumnHeader In FilesListView.Columns
            lv.Columns.Add(listviewCol.Clone)
        Next

        'add the listview to the tabpage
        SplitTabControl.TabPages(SplitTabControl.TabPages.Count - 1).Controls.Add(lv)

        'copy list items from source listview to new list view
        For listItemIndex As Integer = lastSourceListViewIndex To lastSourceListViewIndex + listItemsPerTabPage - 1
            If listItemIndex > sourceListItemCount - 1 Then
                Exit For
            End If
            lv.Items.Add(FilesListView.Items(listItemIndex).Clone)
        Next

        lastSourceListViewIndex = lastSourceListViewIndex + listItemsPerTabPage

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @Andrew-mortimer for your answer, I will try the the code

Comment: it misconception .. I do not create a new tab on listview inside it, it's kinda like 
[ 1 ] [ 2 ] [ 3 ] [ 4 ] button .. and when we click (1), there will be view 10 item first.
But Thank you for your appreciation by making this code, I've tried my own code and successfull